# How does Soldier: 76's ultimate pick targets?

Tags: overwatch

Soldier: 76's ultimate ability is an aimbot, targeting all enemies generally in front of him. But how does this ability pick targets? Is it based on proximity, or is it based on something else?

Additionally, does his ultimate target buildings as well, or does it only target players?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Soldier: 76’s pinpoint targeting visor “locks” his aim on the threat closest to his crosshairs. If an enemy leaves his line of sight, Soldier: 76 can quickly switch to another target.

[source](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/heroes/soldier-76/)

It only targets other heroes.

Comment: This can actually be a downside. Beware of turrets when using his ultimate.